# Parsing JSON object in JQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf, json

I have simple JSON object returned in form

```
{"d":"{\"Name\":\"DMX100\",\"Description\":\"blah blah\",\"ID\":\" 780\",\"Make\":\"2010\"}"}
```

How do I parse it in success.

```
success: function(msg)                  
{                     
    $('#something').html(msg.d.Name);   
}
```

Above code doesnt display Name but when I pass  `$('#something').html(msg.d);`
it shows complete JSON string. How do I reach to individual properties

Thanks

Comment: Clarify - are you using .html with msg.d.Name or msg.d ?

Comment: Install firebug for firefox and console.log(msg.d) - so you can make sure your object isn't being escaped by the .net method.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue ? I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to eval - just use d.Name

(assuming d is a variable from msg.d)

It's also easy to iterate a json object that contains multiple 'rows' using jquery's .each method, as in this example:

```
$.each(msg.d, function() {      
    alert(this.SomeProperty);
});
```

And make sure you have set:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

And finally, use firebug to console.log msg.d

Comment: Hi ScottE,
I am not using eval, It's a commented line should get rid of it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `ajax()`, you can set the `dataType` property to get JSON data. [**Manual**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to eval it, here's how:

```
var data = eval("(" + msg + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery since 1.4 has special method to parse json, and from this version this one is not using eval but native parser.

Take a look here:

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/15/jquery-1-4-and-malformed-json/

and from jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: I have eval as commented line..sorry for the confuson up there.
still couldnt parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(msg)
{
  injectHtml(msg.d);
}

function injectHtml(json) 
{
    //Get data from json
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
    var Name = Description = ID = Make = '';

    $.each(data, function() {
        Name = this.Name;
        Description = this.Description
        ID = this.ID;
        Make = this.Make;
    });

    //Inject 
    $('#something').html(Name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the Accepts header along with ContentType. This will notify the service that it needs the response in JSON and not as plaintext.

```
accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

You can look up examples on how to eat this Request Header using jQuery AJAX.

[Pass accepts header parameter to jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347211/pass-accepts-header-parameter-to-jquery-ajax)