# Pass accepts header parameter to jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I inspect the following code in Chrome Console it shows me a Request header `Accept:undefined`

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: _this.attr('href'),
        accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        
    });
});
```

How do I set accept type as JSON. I don't want to set a custom header or use `beforeSend`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try this ,

```
$.ajax({     
  headers: {          
    Accept: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",         
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"   
  },
  data: "data",    
  success : function(response) {  
    // ...
  }
});
```

See this post for reference:

[Cannot properly set the Accept HTTP header with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145588/cannot-properly-set-the-accept-http-header-with-jquery)

Fixed : Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property list

Comment: chcek the very first parameter http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. I know i can pass headers but why doesn't it work with accepts

Comment: +1 Great, fixed my other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586403/sending-html-data-through-ajax-using-spring-mvc.

Answer (score 36):

There two alternate ways to set accept header, which are as below:

```
1) setRequestHeader('Accept','application/json; charset=utf-8');

2) $.ajax({
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "json",
    accepts: {
        text: "application/json"
    }
});
```

Comment: The 'text' value for IE was killing me.

Answer (score 24):

In recent versions of jQuery, setting "dataType" to an appropriate value also sets the accepts header. For instance, `dataType: "json"` sets the accept header to `Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`.

Answer (score 13):

The other answers do not answer the actual question, but rather provide workarounds which is a shame because it literally takes 10 seconds to figure out what the correct syntax for `accepts` parameter.

The `accepts` parameter takes an object which maps the `dataType` to the `Accept` header. In your case you don't need to even need to pass the `accepts` object, as setting the data type to `json` should be sufficient. However if you do want to configure a custom `Accept` header this is what you do:

`accepts: {"*": "my custom mime type" },`

How do I know? Open jquery's source code and search for "accepts". The very first find tells you all you need to know:

```
    accepts: {
        "*": allTypes,
        text: "text/plain",
        html: "text/html",
        xml: "application/xml, text/xml",
        json: "application/json, text/javascript"
    },
```

As you see the are default mappings to `text`, `html`, `xml` and `json` data types.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/json");
    }, 
    type: "POST",
    //........
});
```

Comment: This is the only solution that I could get working, and I use jQuery 2.0+

Answer (score 6):

Although some of them are correct, I've found quite confusing the previous responses. At the same time, the OP asked for a solution without setting a custom header or using `beforeSend`, so I've being looking for a clearer explanation. I hope my conclusions provide some light to others.

The code

```
jQuery.ajax({
    .... 
    accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    ....
});
```

doesn't work because `accepts` must be a `PlainObject` (not a `String`) according to the jQuery doc (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Specifically, jQuery expect zero or more key-value pairs relating each `dataType` with the accepted MIME type for them. So what I've finally using is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ....
    dataType: 'json',
    accepts: {
        json: 'application/json'
    },
    ....
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me (jQuery 1.9.1). The Accept header gets set to `*.*` (in Chrome and Firefox at least). Using karthick's "headers" option does work tho.

Comment: Yeah, quite, it's a `PlainObject`, but there's not explanation of what the keys should be...

Answer (score 5):

You had already identified the accepts parameter as the one you wanted and keyur is right in showing you the correct way to set it, but if you set DataType to "json" then it will automatically set the default value of accepts to the value you want as per [the jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). So all you need is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: _this.attr('href'),
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) ] )` 
for example:

```
var url="my.php";
$.getJSON( url, myObj )
.done(function( json ) { ... }) /* got JSON from server */
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Failed to obtain JSON data from server: " + err );
  }); /* failed to get JSON */
```

getJSON is shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```