# Is it possible to set a Request Header value with jQuery when using JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers, jsonp

This was a great help to describing what is and how to make jsonp requests. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6879319/371137

I, however, also need to change the Accept value in the request header to 'application/javascript' so my 3rd party server will respond correctly.

There are lots of SO answers pertaining to setting the header values (including [Pass accepts header parameter to jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347211/pass-accepts-header-parameter-to-jquery-ajax)) w/ the API, but none seem to be in conjunction with "jsonp".

I can't seem to figure out from jQuery's documentation how to actually alter the Accept header value when using datatype "jsonp".

beforeSend does nothing. "accepts" does nothing. "headers" seems to be ignored.

I can't even seem to set any custom headers at all.

No matter what i do the Accept header value is always '*/*'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass accepts header parameter to jquery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347211/pass-accepts-header-parameter-to-jquery-ajax)

Comment: So i think the difference is with datatype: "jsonp" does somethings to the headers behind the scenes. ??

Comment: Agreed, not a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. JSONP requests are actually script requests(why the json is wrapped in function) which don't allow headers to be added

Similarly they can't be use for methods like POST

Comment: Looks to me like this is the best answer.  However, I also don't see why this request would need to be JSONP.   From what I can tell (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-anyone-explain-what-jsonp-is-in-layman-terms) with the advent of CORS there's really no benefit to JSONP, right?

Comment: @DanFarrell agree with that. JSONP is now fairly outdated

Comment: I'm actually less familiar w/ JSONP than CORS.. but i was having continual issues w/ pre-flight requests from said 3rd party api. They had previously supported jsonp and made some code changes that now returns applicatoin/json in the response header... this seemed to break my legacy jsonp code. 

I think the answer is ... move to CORS and solve the preflight problem.  I really appreciate both of your's help.

Comment: Yes...if you control the endpoint that serves the json. If you don't ... use a proxy on a server you do control to make the request